# TableView section header in android is blank and clickable

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm using `Xamarin.Forms`, currently trying to make a `TableView` without a section header.  Right now on `iOS` this looks fine as the section header is not visible or clickable, but on `Android` the header is blank, visible, and clickable.

I've tried this http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/18037/tablesection-w-out-header

Code in xaml -

```xml
<TableView>
    <TableView.Root>
      <TableSection>
        <TextCell Text="Login" Command="{Binding Login}" />
        <TextCell Text="Sign Up" Command="{Binding SignUp}" />
        <TextCell Text="About" Command="{Binding About}"/>
      </TableSection>
    </TableView.Root>
  </TableView>
```

Code in c#

```cs
Content = new TableView
{
    Root = new TableRoot 
    {
        new TableSection () 
        {
            new TextCell { Text="Login", Command = Login }, 
            new TextCell { Text="Sign Up", Command = SignUp },
            new TextCell { Text="About", Command = About },
        },
    },
};
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To suppress the header on Android, we use a custom renderer. If `Text` is empty, it hides the cell by removing all children, reducing the height and removing all padding.

```cs
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(TextCell), typeof(ImprovedTextCellRenderer))]

namespace YourSolution.Android
{
    public class ImprovedTextCellRenderer : TextCellRenderer
    {
        protected override global::Android.Views.View GetCellCore(Cell item, global::Android.Views.View convertView, ViewGroup parent, Context context)
        {
            var view = base.GetCellCore(item, convertView, parent, context) as ViewGroup;
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty((item as TextCell).Text)) {
                view.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
                while (view.ChildCount > 0)
                    view.RemoveViewAt(0);
                view.SetMinimumHeight(0);
                view.SetPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
            }
            return view;
        }
    }
}
```

Just copy this class somewhere into your Android project and you should be fine.

Comment: @Falko, how many rows does your TableView have in it? When I apply this solution to my TableView, some rows that are not yet visible have empty content.

Comment: How we can create renderer for winPhone?